# how to vary the content height dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx

I am loading the tab content using

```
tabbar.setContentHref("a1","Home/About");
```

I have anothar alternation is to load the content using .,

```
 tabbar.setContentHtml("<iframe src='/Home/About'>")
```

What I want is that vary the content height dynamically while loading.
I have googled ,but no solutions are working for me.
Is there any other ways to load the content ??.
can any one help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you will know the height, you can use the next approach:

```
<div id="a_tabbar" class="dhtmlxTabBar" tabstyle="silver" imgpath="../dhtmlxTabbar/codebase/imgs/" style="width:755px; color:#FFFFFF;" onbeforeinit="a_tabbar.enableAutoSize(true,true)" oninit="a_tabbar.normalize(755,true); a_tabbar.setTabActive('a1');" offset="15">
<div id="a1" name="Tab 1-1" style="height: 300px; background-color: black;">Content 1</div>
<div id="a2" name="Tab 1-2" style="height: 600px; background-color: #556b2f;">Content 2</div>
</div>
```